# different texture color from the shader compared to the original

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm writing a shader that I am modifying meshstandardmaterial. I want to use maps, roughness map and normality map the same way meshstandardmaterial does. Unfortunately, there was a problem right from the start. The resulting map texture from the shader is darker and slightly redder than the original. I have put a codesanbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-swanson-p6rfi7?file=/src/App.js
that shows my problem. Maybe someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong.

I tried various ways to use the texture in the shader, including outgoinglight as it is in codesanbox. I thought maybe it was a lighting issue, but unfortunately it didn't give the expected results. On the left is a shader sphere, on the right is a meshstandardmaterial. I would like to get the result like on the right. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do two things here

1. first of all, the light color you have to multiply with your texture result, not a mix
2. you can do a gamma color correction to get close to your target, you can read more about gamma correction, for example here - https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction

and here is how modified shader looks like

```
vec3 texture = texture(texture1, vUv).rgb;
vec3 color = outgoingLight * texture.rgb;
  
float gamma = 2.2;
gl_FragColor.rgb = pow(color.rgb, vec3(1.0/gamma));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, maybe it's not perfectly the same as with meshstandardmaterial, but it's definitely better. I've changed the sandbox code to show another problem I'm having. The shader's task is to make a transition between two textures. I've tried to write it so that the roughness properties and normal maps are visible as well as in a meshstandard material. My first problem is with the snow texture (progress value in leva equals 1) it is shinier than the original next to it. The second problem is that I can't get the sparkling effect of point light reflection on the texture.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-swanson-p6rfi7?file=/src/Model.js